# IBAction not getting fired

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have 2 view controllers in my app that user can navigate from one to another. 
In my first view controller I dragged from an icon in the toolbar to the second view controller to setup a segues and selected “show” from the popup.
So far no issue, I can click on the icon in the toolbar and will take me to the second view  controller without any problem.
However I have also created an action from that icon using drag and drop so now I have something like this

```
@IBAction func setting(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    println("Test")
}
```

The problem I have is the setting action is not getting fired when I click on the toolbar icon, however it will navigate to the second view controller without a problem.

Reason I want to call the setting function is to perform something prior to moving the second view controller.

Do you see any problem with the way I have implemented this?

Comment: Do your setting in prepareForSegue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using segue from your storyboard, then that segue is triggered before the button action.If you want to perform some action on your button click, then you have to manually call the segue like this

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueName" sender:sender];
```

then instantiate your segue like this

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YourSegueName"]) 
    {

    }
}
```